# I am having an issue with dual-booting Windows 7 and Windows XP Pro file access.

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I have an XP and a Windows 7 computer and I cannot access the Windows 7 files from within XP.  It asks for a password, and all the passwords I use do not work.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Which username/password are you trying?  Usually, the file can only be accessed by the creator and administrators on the computer, so try using your username/password for Windows 7, not any of the Windows XP accounts.